# Using kleene star with parameter in neo4j query via spring boot

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to do a query like

```
"match (x: Person {name: "Adam"}), (x)-[:friend *..n]-(y) return y"
```

Where n is some parameter. Trying to execute this via spring boot as

`"match (x: Person {name: {name: "Adam"}}), (x)-[:friend *..{distance}]-(y) return y"`  where I have an @Param("name"), @Param("distance") ... it tells me

```
Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. "{id: {param}.id}")
```

Which I can't make sense of, how can I do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you can not use the parameter as the length of the pattern. Alternatively, you can use the [`java.text.MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

```
int distance = 4;
String query = MessageFormat.format(
  "match (x: Person {name: {name: "Adam"}}), (x)-[:friend *..{0}]-(y) return y",
  distance);
```